# Katex auto rendering not working in a Vue project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, katex

I'm trying to implement this Katex auto-rendering extension: https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html, it looks for specific delimiters to find katex strings and renders them in the HTML.

I've followed the instructions and added the CDN to the header of my `index.html` like so:

```
   <!-- KATEX AUTO RENDERING -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-AfEj0r4/OFrOo5t7NnNe46zW/tFgW6x/bCJG8FqQCEo3+Aro6EYUG4+cU+KJWu/X"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script type="module">
      import renderMathInElement from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/contrib/auto-render.mjs";
      renderMathInElement(document.body);
    </script>
```

As a test, I put the following in my `<body>` tag of my `index.html`:

```
 <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        The formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$ will be rendered inline, but $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
        will be rendered as a block element.
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        The formula \(a^2+b^2=c^2\) will be rendered inline, but \[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
        will be rendered as a block element.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
```

It works perfectly, I can see the katex rendered on the screen.

But now I want to add these types of katex formula strings in my other Vue components. I put the exact same formula div in my `Home.vue` component's template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <app-header></app-header>
      <div>
      <div>
        The formula $a^2+b^2=c^2$ will be rendered inline, but $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
        will be rendered as a block element.
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        The formula \(a^2+b^2=c^2\) will be rendered inline, but \[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
        will be rendered as a block element.
      </div>
    </div>

    <textbook-selection></textbook-selection>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

But the katex is not rendered. Why does this happen?

I'm using Vue v2.6.11 with Katex v0.12.0, with vue-cli, vue-router, babel, if those are of any relevance.

Comment: Did you figure it out?